# Keyword 'is' in when Kotlin when-statement

Tags: kotlin

In code I read

```
when (sensorState) {
    SensorState.Available -> TODO("Init Measure")

    is SensorState.Measuring -> {
        sensor.measure()
    }

    is SensorState.Paused -> {
        sensor.pauseMeasuring()
    }

    is SensorState.Failed,
    SensorState.Queued -> {
        sensor.deleteLastMeasurement(id)
    }

    SensorState.NotAvailable,
    SensorState.Completed,
    SensorState.Unknown -> Unit
}
```

Some cases in `when` statement have prepending `is` key and some do not.
What is the difference here?
Which can be preferred?

EDIT:

```
sealed interface SensorState {
    val iconRes: Int
    val sensorState: SensorState

    sealed interface SensorStateWithMeasuredValue : SensorState {
        val measuredValue: Float
    }

    data object Unknown : SensorState {
        override val iconRes: Int = -1
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.UNKNOWN
    }

    data object Available : SensorState {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_available
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.UNKNOWN
    }

    data object NotAvailable : SensorState {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_not_available
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.UNKNOWN
    }

    data object Queued : SensorState {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_on_queue
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.QUEUED
    }

    data class Paused(override val measuredValue: Float) : SensorStateWithMeasuredValue {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_paused
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.STOPPED
    }

    data class Measuring(override val measuredValue: Float) : SensorStateWithMeasuredValue {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_in_measured
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.Measuring
    }

    data object Completed : SensorState {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_complete
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.COMPLETED
    }

    data class Failed(override val measuredValue: Float) : SensorStateWithMeasuredValue {
        override val iconRes: Int = R.drawable.sensor_status_failed
        override val sensorState: SensorState = SensorState.FAILED
    }

    companion object {
        val allSensorStates = listOf(
            Failed(0.0f),
            Paused(0.0f),
            Measuring(0.0f),
            Queued,
            Completed,
            Available,
            NotAvailable,
            Unknown,
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm aware you don't have a choice: it depends on what the type of the object is you are evaluating. Are you able to share the types of, say, `SensorState.Available` and `SensorState.Measuring`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These are two of the four forms that you can put in a `when` expression that has a bound value (the bound value is the `(sensorState)` after the `when` keyword).

`is T` checks the bound value against a type `T`. If the bound value is an instance of `T`, then that branch is executed.

Without `is`, it is simply an expression. If the bound value is equal (according to `==`) to the expression, then that branch is executed.

The other two forms is `in someCollection` and `else`. See also the [Kotlin Language Specification](https://kotlinlang.org/spec/expressions.html#when-expressions) for more info.

The code here doesn't care about the values of the properties of `sensorState`, and just wants to check its type. `SensorState.Measuring` and `is SensorState.Paused` etc are data classes, and one can create different instances of them, so the code uses `is` to check their types only.

On the other hand, `SensorState.NotAvailable` and `SensorState.Completed` etc are `object`s. `object`s are singletons - there can only be one instance for each `object` type. The name of the `object` is also an expression to refer to that single instance.

Because of this, instead of checking the type of `sensorState`  like this (which is also valid):

```
is SensorState.NotAvailable -> { ... }
```

The code just checks whether `sensorState` is *equal* to the instance `SensorState.NotAvailable`. If `sensorState` is of *type* `SensorState.NotAvailable`, then it must be the *instance* `SensorState.NotAvailable`, because there is *exactly one* such instance.

Note that `SensorState.NotAvailable` (and the other `objects` in your code) can refer to two things depending on context - the *type* `SensorState.NotAvailable`, and the only *instance* of the type `SensorState.NotAvailable`.

For more info about `object`s, see the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#object-declarations-overview).

Finally, `SensorState` here represents an [algebraic data type](https://medium.com/sharenowtech/kotlin-adt-74472319962a). See the link for more info.

Comment: The OP has since supplied the definition of `SensorState` which confirms all of your assumptions. I would also be interested to know if you think it would be a good idea to use `is` for everything (both classes and objects) in the `when` statement, for uniformity?

Comment: @k314159 IMO yes. I think it is more readable.